# Partitioning Hasn't ended for 2-3 hours

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I'm installing Ubuntu on my laptop, but it's been partitioning for the past 2-3 hours.

Any ideas on what to do now ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you resizing or moving a large partition? If so, that can take a long while and is normal. If you are partitioning an empty drive on the other side it should be over in a matter of seconds. In the later case I would just restart and try again.

There might be some RAID or encryption setups that could also take a considerable amount of time, but I have no detailed experience with that.

Another possibility is a hardware/driver problem, have a look at the output of `dmesg` for anything that looks like an error message. A broken drive should spam the dmesg output with new errors constantly.

For further help provide the output of `dmesg` and your partition layout along with the tools you use.

Another way to get more information would be to use `strace -p PID` (replace `PID` with the process id of the partitioning process), `top` or `iotop`. They can tell you if the partitioning process is currently doing something or stuck.